# UFT: How can I call a gui test with the result of an api test?

Tags: automated-testing, rest-api, uft

The result of the rest service returns me a url to download a file, I would need to use that url in a gui test to open it in the IE browser, can someone help me how to pass that parameter?

My test contains:

1. Start GUI test
2. Action 1 (Call to existing API test)
3. Action 2 (open browser with result API test)
4. End GUI test

UFT 14.51 with Vbs

Thanks!!

Comment: What framework and language are you using for each of the steps ?

Comment: I'm using UFT 14.51 with vbs, thanks

Comment: Does this help: https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/15.0/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/z_Ch_Integ_API_Tests.htm ?

Comment: Thanks, I saw it, what it does not explain is how to extract the result of the run api test and consume it in another action with the gui test or I have not understood it well.

Comment: I haven't an idea about how to do that in UFT, but easily u can do your requirement using tools like Katalone Studio, Ranorax Studio